# Filter a response using Rx and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a call in Rx like so:

```
rxHelper.manageSubscription(HavocService.getInstance().getHavocAPI().getAllTasks(userId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .compose(RxTiPresenterUtils.deliverLatestToView(this))
                .subscribe(response -> {
                    this.mStandardTaskResponse = response;
                    mListOfTasks = mStandardTaskResponse.getTasks();
                    getView().setTaskList(mListOfTasks);
                    getView().setLoading(false);
                }, throwable -> {
                    getView().setLoading(false);
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                })
        );
```

where the `response` is of the following type

```
public class StandardTaskResponse {

    /**
     * Whether or not there was an error with the response
     */
    public boolean status;

    /**
     * List of Tasks
     */
    @SerializedName("doc")
    public List<Task> tasks;

    /**
     * Gets the array of Tasks from the response
     *
     * @return the List of Tasks
     */
    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }
}
```

I want to filter the response's Task list. For example, I only want the List to include items where `TaskFromList.getStatus() == 2` for example.

How do I do this with Rx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```
rxHelper.manageSubscription(HavocService.getInstance().getHavocAPI().getAllTasks(USER)
                .flatMap(response -> Observable.from(response.getTasks()))
                //filter out Tasks that are ARCHIVED or DONE
                .filter(task -> task.getStatus() == TaskStatusEnum.INCOMPLETE)
                .toList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .compose(RxTiPresenterUtils.deliverLatestToView(this))
                .subscribe(list -> {
                    mListOfTasks = list;
                    getView().setTaskList(mListOfTasks);
                    getView().setLoading(false);
                }, throwable -> {
                    getView().setLoading(false);
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                })
        );
```