# Filter list of items using RxJava

Tags: rx-java

How do you filter a list of items with RxJava ?

I have the following code and `loadData()` emits a `List<Chatroom>` :

```
repository.loadData()
        .subscribe(chatrooms -> {
            view.showData(chatrooms);
            view.showEmptyState(chatrooms.size() == 0);
        }, throwable -> Log.i("OnError", "onLoadChatrooms ", throwable)));
```

and I want to apply filter after `loadData()`. You can see my solution on the next code snippet but maybe there's a better way ?

```
 repository.loadData()
        .map(chatrooms -> {

            List<Chatroom> openChatrooms = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Chatroom chatroom: chatrooms){
                if (!chatroom.getBlocked().equals(IS_BLOCKED)) {
                    openChatrooms.add(chatroom);
                }
            }
            return openChatrooms;

        })
        .subscribe(chatrooms -> {
            view.showData(chatrooms);
            view.showEmptyState(chatrooms.size() == 0);
        }, throwable -> Log.i("OnError", "onLoadChatrooms ", throwable)));
```

Comment: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter a response using Rx and Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096608/filter-a-response-using-rx-and-retrofit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 loadData()
     // Opther operations if any
     .filter((chatroom -> { return !chatroom.getBlocked().equals(IS_BLOCKED);})
     .toList()
     .subscribe(getObserver()); // implement your getObserver() method for observer.
```

This should help.

Comment: Hi. if i only want to get 1 data, then break other, how to do it?

Comment: Try using take(n) operator. Pass 1 in argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fine, if not "functional" in style.

Normally, I would write something like -

```swift
loadData()
        .flatMap(chatrooms -> { return Observable.from(chatrooms); })
        .filter(chatroom -> { return !chatroom.getBlocked().equals(IS_BLOCKED); })
        .toList();
```